# Container override not working for ECS using EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, task, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create a new task inside ECS -> New CLuster.

I am getting 2 errors,

1. The container override is not loading. The section just shows loading indefinitely. Screenshot:
   [image: ECS_Container_Override_Error]
2. When I provide a new TaskDefinition, I see the error : No active task definition found. Screenshot: [image: ECS_task_definition_error]

I am very new to AWS and ECS. Can someone pls help me find out what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. "The container override is not loading." --> you would have to first select a task definition, as this section is for overwriting the configurations in the task definition.
2. "When I provide a new TaskDefinition, I see the error : No active task definition found." --> you would have to first [create a task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html)

I would recommend the official [tutorials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-tutorials.html) and official [ECS workshop](https://ecsworkshop.com/) for beginners.